# Can I use 'global people' to say people from around the world?

Tags: meaning

I need to write a short sentence where I refer to people from all around the world. Can I use 'global people'? Or is it a totally different concept?
Thanks!

Comment: Depending on how the sentence is worded, maybe *people worldwide* or *global population*.

Comment: I suppose *global people* could also mean people who are well travelled (Which is not what you mean) so introduces ambiguity.

Answer (score -1):

**I need to write a short sentence where I refer to people from all around the world. Can I use 'global people'? Or is it a totally different concept? Thanks!**

No I think it is not really a good idea. **Globe also means a sphere or ball** shaped so we would have **spherical people**. Global people, make cartoon characters something like weebles, spring to mind. To comment in a more serious fashion it is an unusual use of the word Global. How about Multinational or Multicultural, or Interracial.

However I think I would try to use **The Global Community** that should work, if you can fit it in.